# react native 0.27 addListener is not a function

Tags: react-native

I upgrade react-native from 0.26.3 to 0.27.2, but catch some errors

1.for Android: Module is not a registered callable module

2.for iOS: this._nativeModule.addListener is not a function(In 'this._nativeModule.addListener(eventType)','this._nativeModule.addListener' is undifined)

i don't know why, please give me some help, thx for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to remove node_modules and npm install again. Good luck guy!